# PL/SQL Update Query

Tags: sql, oracle

Attempting to update a table I have created with null values from another table I have created in PL/SQL:
I was able to utilize the below update in SQL Server but am running into issues within PL/SQL (dont ask why I am running it in both) 
Overall_Inventory = Table created with some populated values and some null valuse; this is the table requiring updates to those null values
task_table        = Table also created, but contains value needing to be updated into T1

```
update dbh.overall_inventory
   set dbh.overall_inventory.case_due_date = tsk.TASK_ACTION_TIMESTAMP
  from dbh.overall_inventory, 
       (SELECT tsk.INQ_KEY,
               min(tsk.TASK_ACTION_TIMESTAMP) as TASK_ACTION_TIMESTAMP
          FROM dbh.task_table tsk
               inner join dbh.overall_inventory Inv 
                       on tsk.INQ_KEY = inv.inq_key
         where tsk.ACTION_CD = '324' 
         group by tsk.INQ_KEY
        ) tsk
    where tsk.INQ_KEY = dbh.overall_inventory.inq_key`
```

Comment: There is no `FROM` statement in Oracle update syntax. Only a `WHERE` clause. Check [here](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/update.php) for syntax examples.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle doesn't support `from` clause in the `update` statement.  In this situation [merge](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606) statement can be used.

```
merge into overall_inventory oi
  using (select tsk.inq_key,
                min(tsk.task_action_timestamp) as task_action_timestamp
           from task_table tsk
                join overall_inventory Inv 
                  on tsk.inq_key = inv.inq_key
          where tsk.action_cd = '324' 
          group by tsk.inq_key) tsk
     on (tsk.inq_key = oi.inq_key )
when matched then 
   update 
      set case_due_date = tsk.task_action_timestamp
    where case_due_date is null    -- as I understood only NULL values  
                                   -- need to be updated
```

**Note**: Not tested because no sample data and desired result were provided.

Comment: I believe that is going to work!!! Thank you very much. I had just discovered the "Merge" command in another thread but could not figure out how to utilze it properly in this situation. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for update over a select:

```
UPDATE (

  SELECT product_id, category_id 

  FROM product) st

SET st.category_id = 5 

WHERE st.category_id = 4;
```